# How to access the modelview matrix in kivy?

Tags: python, opengl, kivy

I am writing a python application using Kivy for rendering some graphics. I would like to find out how to get access to the current modelview matrix within kivy, the same matrix as in the vertex shader.

Here is my example code (Python 2.7, Kivy 1.9):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix
from kivy.resources import resource_find
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

vertices = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
indices = [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
vformat = [(b'v_pos', 3, 'float'), (b'v_normal', 3, 'float')]

class Renderer(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Renderer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.canvas = RenderContext(compute_normal_mat=True)
        self.canvas.shader.source = resource_find('simple.glsl')
        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()
            Translate(0, -1, -3)
            self.rot = Rotate(1, 0, 1, 0)
            UpdateNormalMatrix()
            self.mesh = Mesh(vertices=vertices, indices=indices,
                             fmt=vformat, mode='triangles')
            PopMatrix()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_glsl, 1 / 60.)

    def update_glsl(self, delta):
        asp = self.width / float(self.height)
        proj = Matrix().view_clip(-asp, asp, -1, 1, 1, 100, 1)
        self.canvas['projection_mat'] = proj
        self.rot.angle += delta * 100

        print self.canvas['modelview_mat']

class RendererApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Renderer()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RendererApp().run()
```

and the shader file *simple.glsl*:

```
---VERTEX SHADER-----------------------------------

attribute vec3  v_pos;
attribute vec3  v_normal;
uniform mat4 modelview_mat;
uniform mat4 projection_mat;
varying vec4 normal_vec;

void main (void) {
    normal_vec = vec4(v_normal, 0.0);
    gl_Position = projection_mat * modelview_mat * vec4(v_pos, 1.0);
}


---FRAGMENT SHADER---------------------------------

uniform mat4 normal_mat;
varying vec4 normal_vec;

void main (void){
    vec4 v_normal = normalize( normal_mat * normal_vec ) ;
    float theta = clamp(abs(dot(v_normal, vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0))), 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(theta, theta, theta, 1.0);
}
```

In the function `update_glsl` I need the current modelview matrix for some calculations. I tried `self.canvas['modelview_mat']`, but this give me always the identity matrix.